# Written Torah in Messianic era

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, written-torah

In the brief clip [linked](https://www.instagram.com/p/BywFU_HFHVz/) the speaker says that “in the end of days when *Moshiah* comes and prophesy comes back they’re going to write all about Jewish history, they’re going to write about *galus* (exile), they’re going to write and it’s going to become *Torah She’bichtav* (Written Torah)... there’s going to be *pesukim* (verses) and *pesukim*... about the sacrifices of *Yidden* (Jews)..”.

Is there any source that describes such amendments to the Torah?

Comment: They probably mean it will become Navi or Kesuvim?

Comment: Who are they that are "going to write"?

Comment: Sounds more like addenda than amendments.

Comment: @AlBerko why does it have to be anyone in particular?  Probably "they" will start out as random people but through their own efforts will become tzadikim.

Comment: @Heshy Possibly, but question would still stand, at least for me.

Comment: @AlBerko Your guess is as good as mine.